# Gradle offline how to cache the dependencies

Tags: android, linux, caching, gradle, build.gradle

I am doing nightly gradle builds on a server where I checkout the repositories from git and build them.However, there is a proxy where gradle cannot download any repository. I tried running gradlew offline mode then I get an error telling me that

> "No cached version of" and then the name of the dependency.

This is obviously because I never downloaded the dependency, I was thinking of manually downloading the dependencies cache them and use that gradle cache on the server where builds can access it. My question is as follows :

1. Is there any way I can download a .jar file or .pom file manually and then cache them ?_
2. How would i cache a jar file in the $Home/.gradle/caches directory ? I tried just putting it there but it doesn't work .

any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just run the build with Internet? As long as you don't change the dependencies you should be able to build offline from then on. But of course this is far from an optimal solution.

Comment: Can't you just configure the proxy in your gradle.properties file? That would permanently solve the problem. No offline mode required.

Comment: The company I work for doesn't allow me to configure the proxy....it wants an offline build

Comment: But how do they think this is supposed to work? Regardless of if you manually put all the dependencies in a local maven repository or if Gradle downloads them automatically those dependencies still come from the exactly same place - from jcenter or mavenCentral. There is no benefit to doing this, just a lot more unnecessary work.

Comment: However one solution I can think of would be for your company to host a private maven server - for example Nexus or Artifactory - and then pulling all required dependencies from there. In that case your company would be in full control of the dependencies used for your build and at the same time you and the other developers don't have to do anything complicated to configure this. You just have to set your maven server in your build.gradle files instead of jcenter or mavenCentral.

Comment: Regardless while its possible to do you what you are asking about I would strongly discourage you from curating your dependencies manually on your build server. This would be A LOT of painstaking work. Depending on the size of your project you would have to manually manage hundreds of dependencies. Obviously this would be completely unfeasible for any human to do especially when a computer can do it for you in literally seconds.

Comment: yeah you are right I like the idea of having a private maven server , I will try to figure something out thanks a lot you have helped a lot.

Comment: @XaverKapeller The problem is, that there are countries in that world, where the computer is in fact not doing it for you in seconds. I for example have been waiting fifteen minutes for it to build, until some connection error appears and the whole cache is invalid. So sometimes manual downloads are just better.

Answer (score 4):

Usually Gradle retrieves dependencies on demand, only if and when they are need. To make Gradle download all dependencies beforehand (and thus populate the local cache), you can use a task like

```
task resolveAllDependencies {
    description "Resolves all transitive dependencies (e.g. to build offline later)."

    doLast {
        configurations.all {
            it.resolve()
        }
    }
}
```

After running this task, you should be able to successfully build with `--offline`.

Comment: is there any way i can use this same cache on different computers? If I copy the cache would the build with --offline still work?

Comment: Only if the absolute path to the cache directory is the same on all machines. This currently is a limitation in Gradle, see [this issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2690).

Comment: Okay sschuberth thank you a lot for your advice I will try to figure something out.

Comment: Fixed in Gradle 6.1: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1338#issuecomment-565691159

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio sync the dependencies once then go to

- File > Settings > Build & Execution > Gradle > Enable Offline Mode > Ok!

Comment: What IDE are these instructions for?

Comment: Android Studio.